# MediaRecorder not recordng audio consistently

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

I have tried to record audio from MIC using following code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder= new MediaRecorder();
recorder.reset();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);

if(recorder!=null)
{
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}
```

Some time this code records audio perfectly, but some times recorded file only has 6 bytes.

I don't understand why same code not works every time.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Those 6 bytes are the AMR file header, so apparently the recorder wasn't able to get any audio data (or wasn't able to encode or write the data to your output file). Which device is this on? What if you explicitly set the sampling rate to 8000 Hz and the number of channels to 1?

Comment: I am using Lenovo ThinkPad. I am not explicitly setting the sampling rate and number of channel.

Comment: @Michael Is this possible Mediarecorder not getting any data, because at the same time any other app running the Media recorder?

Comment: Only one app can record audio at any given time on Android (except if the vendor has implemented some sort of stream splitter, which most of them don't).

Comment: @Michael OK. Suppose if my app starts recording second time (i.e. another app still using MediaRecorder instance before using my app) then in my app Media recorder instance will crashed with exception or the media recorder object still running but not receiving any audio data?

Comment: That will probably be implementation-specific.